# Angular Universal - EmptyError: no elements in sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli, angular-universal

I've been trying to integrate Angular Universal with my app and it has been a big big struggle. We already fixed a lot of issues but we are already stuck on this one for 2 days now. Any help is really appreciated.

So the build runs fine, the error only occurs when we try to launch the website.
This is the error:

> EmptyError: no elements in sequence
>       at new EmptyError (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:147171:28)
>       at C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:147226:518
>       at Object.complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:170696:23)
>       at TapSubscriber.module.exports.TapSubscriber._complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:125494:31)
>       at TapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59791:18)
>       at TakeSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59809:26)
>       at TakeSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59791:18)
>       at FilterSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59809:26)
>       at FilterSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59791:18)
>       at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59809:26)
>       at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59791:18)
>       at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.*complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59809:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:59791:18)
>       at State.module.exports.Subject.complete (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:55713:21)
>       at State.module.exports.State.ngOnDestroy (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:131851:14)
>       at callNgModuleLifecycle (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:8840:31)
>       at NgModuleRef*.module.exports.NgModuleRef_.destroy (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:9458:9)
>       at C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:4766:73
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at PlatformRef.module.exports.PlatformRef.destroy (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:4766:31)
>       at C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:170216:22
>       at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:394223:26)
>       at Zone.module.exports.Zone.run (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:393973:43)
>       at C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:394707:34
>       at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:394256:31)
>       at Zone.module.exports.Zone.runTask (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:394023:47)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:394430:35)
>       at module.exports.ZoneTask.invokeTask (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:394335:21)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:394320:48)
>       at data.args.(anonymous function) (C:\Projects\beatstars-marketplace-v2\dist\server.js:395173:25)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

We researched a lot already and think is something related to rxjs but really not sure what.
We tried checking all of our first() usages all seemed alright. We tried removing all our canActivate guards, also didn't worked and we also tried adding and removing pathMatch: full from routes. These were the solutions for the problem that we found on the internet and nothing worked.

This is our package.json:

```
 {
   "name": "project-name",
   "version": "0.1.105",
   "license": "MIT",
   "scripts": {
     "ng": "ng",
     "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --disable-host-check",
     "dev": "ng serve",
     "hmr": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr",
     "local": "ng serve --environment=local",
     "mock-api-dev": "concurrently \"ng serve\" \"node api/api.js\"",
     "test": "ng test",
     "lint": "ng lint",
     "e2e": "ng e2e",
     "build:server:prod": "ng run beatstars-marketplace-v2.1:server && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
     "build:browser:prod": "ng build --prod",
     "build:prod": "npm run build:server:prod && npm run build:browser:prod",
     "server": "node local.js"
   },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.2",
     "@angular/common": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/compiler": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/core": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/forms": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/http": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/material": "^6.4.2",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.2",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.2",
     "@angular/router": "6.1.2",
     "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.41-beta.110",
     "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.1",
     "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
     "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
     "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
     "@ngx-share/core": "^6.0.1",
     "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^9.0.0",
     "@types/algoliasearch": "^3.27.5",
     "algoliasearch": "^3.29.0",
     "body-parser": "latest",
     "canvas-toBlob": "^1.0.0",
     "compression": "latest",
     "core-js": "^2.4.1",
     "cors": "~2.8.4",
     "cropperjs": "^1.0.0-rc",
     "d3": "^4.10.2",
     "dom-autoscroller": "^2.3.3",
     "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
     "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
     "lodash": "^4.17.5",
     "ng-lazyload-image": "^4.0.0",
     "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.6",
     "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
     "ng2-dragula": "^2.0.2",
     "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
     "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.0",
     "ngx-clipboard": "^11.1.1",
     "ngx-color-picker": "^6.6.0",
     "ngx-cookie": "^4.0.1",
     "ngx-editor": "3.2.1",
     "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
     "ngx-page-scroll": "^5.0.0",
     "ngx-slick": "^0.2.0",
     "reselect": "^3.0.0",
     "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
     "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
     "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
     "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
     "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.2",
     "@angular/cli": "6.1.2",
     "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.2",
     "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
     "@types/compression": "^0.0.36",
     "@types/cors": "^2.8.4",
     "@types/cropperjs": "^1.1.1",
     "@types/d3": "^4.10.1",
     "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
     "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
     "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
     "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
     "@types/uuid": "^3.4.3",
     "@types/youtube": "^0.0.30",
     "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
     "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
     "express": "^4.15.4",
     "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
     "karma": "~1.4.1",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
     "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
     "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
     "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
     "prettier": "^1.14.2",
     "protractor": "~5.1.0",
     "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
     "tslint": "^5.7.0",
     "tslint-eslint-rules": "^4.1.1",
     "typescript": "2.9.2"
   }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: That error is thrown if an observable - to which `first`, `last` or `single` has been applied - completes without emitting a value. Of those, `first` is the most commonly used, so I'd suggest looking at any observables that have that applied. If it makes sense for the observable to complete without emitting, use `take(1)` instead of `first`, as the former won't throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I always assumed that first() did unsubscribe automatically so I didn't needed to unsubscribe manually. But with Angular Universal using .withBrowserTransition, my main app component is destroyed before my first() is complete so I need to unsubscribe manually.

Answer (score 0):

To find what triggered it you can put a breakpoint in `EmptyErrorImpl` in `vendor.js`.

[image]

Then once it's triggered you can look at the call stack to try to see stack variables that might give clues as to what failed. You may well not see your own code file shown explicitly in the stack trace because of the async nature of angular - but you can use this method to get clues and track down the source.

I must cautiously add though that Angular uses `EmptyError` for flow control with respect to routing. So don't assume that just because you get an `EmptyError` it actually is unrecoverable - it's used here to detect a non-match for a list of routes (by catching the error):

[image]

Comment: Also `take(1)` can often be safer than `first()` if your source is 'allowed' to complete without emitting.